# Javascript in a text box

Tags: javascript, textbox

I am trying to figure out how to generate javascript then put that javascript into a text box where users can copy it, similiar to how modernizr lets you configure the library then down loaded it http://www.modernizr.com/download/#-iepp-cssclasses-load. I created some javascript as a string, but when I put it into a text box it formats it in a way that I do not want %26%2360script%20src%3D%22http%3A//

```
<textarea id="code">
```

```
function renderAd(size){
    var sizes= size.split("x");
    var code = $("#code");
    var adCode = escape('&#60script src="{{ sitelocation }}/js/"&#61&#60/script&#61&#60script&#60(function(){var settings =     {"size":"'+ size +'};Setup(Settings);})();&#60/script&#61')
    code.val(adCode);   
}
```

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks,
CG

Comment: I have tried it with and with and without escape() with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var path = "/path/to";
$('#code').val("<script src=\"http://someurl.com"+path+"\">alert(\"hello\");</script>");
```

withouth any problem...

Comment: that works ok from a console, but in firefox the </script> in the string is getting rendered and breaking the code block. Putting the rest of the code as text on the page.

Comment: Aha, it seems this was a silly mistake I just needed to escape the close script <\/script> to get the about working :) thanks